# Query timeout for changing storage engine of MySQL table

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, myisam

I have a table in MySQL having 700 million rows. I want to change its storage engine from InnoDB to MyISAM but the SQL query to do so is taking a lot of time to execute.

Below is the query :-

```
ALTER TABLE table ENGINE=MyISAM
```

In phpMyAdmin and MySQL workbench this query is getting timed out.

Is this query supposed to take a lot of time, given the fact that I have very large amount of data, if so what I need to do to make it successfully execute?

Note :- I have decided to switch to MyISAM because there will be more reads and very few writes on this table.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You can try first of all to create new MyISAM empty table and then insert data from another table?

I dont have so big table to test this in that scale, in my biggest table it takes almost the same.

It's important to look at indexes, because rebulding then sometimes takes sooo looonngggg.

Comment: I don't know why this is not happening, I think I need to set up a CRON job for this... I have tried deleting the index but neither index is getting deleted nor the storage engine..

Comment: Cron or use `SCREEN`. I was wondering why InnoDB to MyISAM ? InoDB is better, faster and more secure... Why ?

Comment: I read many forums, people says MyIsam is better when you have fewer writes and much more reads... So I wanted to experiments with this because database is slow..